# How to avoid generating .crc file in spark saveAsHadoopFile()?

Tags: java, apache-spark, crc

Is there any configuration to turn off generating .crc file while using `saveAsHadoopFile` method in java - apache spark?

I using Apache Spark 1.6.2 and running my application in standalone mode.

Comment: Please provide some context information about your problem. At least, which language are you using ? Please edit your question accordingly

Comment: @Pom12 i have mentioned that i am using Java above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt found any way to avoid creating .crc files while using saveAsHadoopFile() method.
Hence i wrote an utility to delete those unwanted .crc and .SUCCESS files.